# ActiveRecord find if a record contain certain ID

Tags: activerecord

Suppose an ActiveRecord named "Relationships". It has an attribute "participants" which is an array containing people ID.
Now I want to find the records that contain a certain people ID. How should I query it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want to do is something like this:

```
    Student.where(:grade => [9,11,12])
```

as seen here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html